# How to handle a scenario where server fails to respond in time with some arbitrary response, but later the transaction is processed?

Tags: transaction

1. Client sends request to deduct his account balance for registering with a service.

   balance=balance-fee
2. Server takes a lot of time to process the request.
3. Since server was taking lot of time, client is notified by a middleman between client and server (the one who's negotiating with both client and server), "Timeout".
4. But after some time, in server the balance gets deducted from client's account.

Can a software handle this scenario?

Answer (score 7):

> Client sends request to deduct his account balance for registering with a service.
>
> balance=balance-fee

How real business systems work isn't generally as simple as this, and rather than asking "how software handles this" as if the problem is unique to computer software, it would be more relevant to go and study *how businesses handle orders, invoices, and payments*, because they've been doing the same thing for centuries, including through the eras of postal mail, telegraph, telephone, and internet.

Often, the laws of a jurisdiction say exactly how things *must* be done, so that someone writing software is not free to simply imagine how they wish to do things.

Generally speaking, accountancy is the profession concerned with this area which intersects record-keeping, law, and the mechanics of trading with the marketplace (including how the exchange of money and things are coordinated).

What the client of a business typically does to trigger a business transaction, is send an order for goods and services at an already-agreed price.

From there on, unless the client submits a cancellation which is received by the business, then the serving business will endeavour on its own initiative to provide the things and collect the price.

If there is any kind of "timeout" on the initial communication of the order, so that the client is unsure what state the business is in, then the client simply re-establishes communication and asks the business where it is up to.

Typically, all communication protocols have some kind of waiting period where an originator waits for an acknowledgement from the receiving party. If an acknowledgement is not received, then that party will try again.

There is always inherently some minimum period of time where one side will not know what the other is doing, and this period may become especially large if communications are unreliable.

Typically also, a client business will mark their order with a unique reference number of their own choosing (separate from any number which the serving business may later assign to the same order when received), so that if the client has many orders outstanding and if they do call the serving business to enquire about a specific one, the business can identify what specific order the client is enquiring about and whether they have received it or not.

Comment: ...but the question was not about general idea or mechanics of the timeouts it seems?

Comment: @Jas, to me the question seemed to be someone with no idea, asking how a business transaction is executed. It was never said explicitly, but I read the OP as implicitly asking how they would know the outcome of the transaction, if the comms session timed out before the acknowledgement - this being relevant to whether they should retry the transaction or not, since retrying when the first attempt had already succeeded would (in their understanding) cause a second fee to be levied.

Comment: Well the OPs formulation could have been better and one needs to read carefully, but actually they are describing a fairly specific case, not asking about general use-case for timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems your problem is that in the case of long running server-side processing, eventually the HTTP stack on either the client or the server machine will terminate the connection, due to timeout settings.

To handle this, in the classic scenario you could have client actually issue two types of http requests:

- The first one to initiate the request and return immediately with server acknowledgment (payment initiated). Consider this as a kind of initiation command.
- The second one to "poll" or query the server for current status. This one either happens once or multiple times. Consider this as a sort of a "status update" command.

Alternative to this would be running a small "callback" server on the client side as well, and instead of the client issuing the second "status" request, having server issue a "completion" http request to the client. However this one is a bit more complicated and opens issues with regards to security as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are an almost infinite number of ways you can handle this, what you want to do depends on your requirements. One obvious way in your example is for the client to generate a unique ID for every request; when it gets a timeout, it can retry and get told that the request has already been processed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer: If this is say a monthly payment, say for a gym membership, and you deliver the goods anyway, you would retry. If I’m buying an item, and without the payment going through you tell me that the item won’t be delivered, then you would cancel the payment. Cancelling should cancel a payment *once* even when called multiple times, and even if the payment arrives after it has been cancelled.